# How to filter and remove duplicate JSON List?

Tags: list, filter, dart, flutter, dropdown

I have a local JSON file as shown below and I load it into my flutter project using "**await rootBundle.loadString(****)**".  I decoded to map as "**Map _mapCompany = jsonDecode(jsonComapany)**" than later assign map to list as "_tmpCompany = _mapComapany["companyBranch"];"

Now I need to use filter to get [companyName] and also I need to remove duplicate [companyName] and load to dropdown button.

I use var "_result = new Collection(_tmpCompany).distinct()" to remove duplicate but how can I assign _result.toList() to List _comapnyName; or to dropdown button?

Once the first dropdown loads I use on change event to load branch list using filter. How can I do that?

```
{  
   “companyBranch”:[  
      {  
         "companyCode":"1",
         "companyName”:”COMAPANY A”,
         "branchCode”:”855”,
         "branchName”:”BRANCH A1”
      },
      {  
         "companyCode":"1",
         "companyName”:”COMPANY A”,
         "branchCode":"856",
         "branchName”:”BRANCH A2“
      },
      {  
         "companyCode":"10",
         "companyName”:”COMAPNY B”,
         "branchCode":"860",
         "branchName”:”BRANCH B1”
      },
      {  
         "companyCode":"10",
         "companyName”:”COMPANY B”,
         "branchCode":"861",
         "branchName”:”BRANCH B2”
      },
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
var uniqueCompanyNames = _tmpCompany.map<String>(
    (c) => (c as List)['companyName'] as String)
    .toSet().toList()
```

Comment: how to assign uniqueCompanyNames to dropdown I am getting error

Comment: What's the error? Please add the code to your question that causes this error.